# Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 71 failed

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, java, updates, jdk

I want to install Xamarin in Windows 8.1.

It requires to install Java Development Kit 1.6 or above (32-bit). When I try to install JDK, I get this error message"

[image]

I'm using Windows 8.1 x64. How can I get it installed?

Comment: I suggest using [JavaRA](https://singularlabs.com/software/javara) to nuke everything Java then use that to reinstall the current version of `Java 1.8` instead of `Java 1.7 Update 71`

Answer (score 0):

Hey man I just found out how to fix this when trying to install it my self.
what you want to do is first install this software http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/            What this does is when right clicking on a file it lets you well. take ownership of that file. so next step after you install that is to hold down the windows and R key what will open Run now type %temp% and press enter. this will take you to the temp folder what i want you to do is go back one folder so you now see the Temp folder not the stuff inside it right click on that folder and take ownership now just try to install your java again